# How can I map sso accounts to EKS cluster in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a EKS cluster and I'd like to add more sso users to the role. Because all developers login to AWS using their sso accounts.

I read this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html and it mentioned how to map IAM users or roles to k8s but it doesn't say how to map sso users.

Is it not supported? or is there a way to do that?

Comment: Perhaps this [article](https://www.powerupcloud.com/aws-eks-authentication-and-authorization-using-aws-single-signon/) can help you.

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67686320/how-can-i-grant-eks-cluster-permission-to-aws-sso-user/72043806#72043806