# How can I grant eks cluster permission to aws sso user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I deployed a EKS cluster via a IAM user and need to give full cluster permission to other aws sso users. I followed this instruction https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html but still can't make it work.

I got below error when run this command by a sso user:

```
$ kubectl get pods
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

In the doc they say to create `aws-auth` ConfigMap to map the role as below. But I am not sure what the role arn I should specify. I am using EKS + Fargate so there is no `node group` or `node instance` in my cluster. So what kind of role should I specify in below configuration>

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: <ARN of instance role (not instance profile)>
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:bootstrappers
        - system:nodes
```

Answer (score 5):

You should specify:

```
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<aws_account_id>:role/<federated_user>
  username: '{{SessionName}}'
  groups:
    - system:masters
```

Please note that `<aws_account_id>` is the ID of the AWS account in which the EKS cluster is created, and `<federated_user>` is the SSO user with which you are accessing this account. This policy will add admin access rights to your k8s cluster. You can obtain the `<federated_user>` by logging into an account with that user and in the upper right corner do expand and you will see Federated user. Copy it, and it will look something like this `AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_9999bb9bbbbfff/administrator`. Take just the first part before the forward slash.

Comment: Does this answer solves your problem? If yes please mark it as solved

Comment: Thank you @GertvandenBerg. Updated my answer to comply with your note

Answer (score -1):

There is a great article explaining your scenario

https://medium.com/swlh/secure-an-amazon-eks-cluster-with-iam-rbac-b78be0cd95c9

Comment: This type of answer isn't as helpful as you think. In the future, the article may be removed and then the answer becomes useless for future readers. You'll often find links like this in the comments so as to still be helpful to the OP if you don't have the time to write up a full answer yourself.